# CLI interace to KDE's notifier

Tags: command-line, kde, d-bus

I think KDE's notifier is pretty sweet. I was thinking... how useful might it be if my system logs were also sent there, so they would pop so I could see them. I think the first step of this is to figure out how to send messages to the notifier via CLI.

here's the [kde forum discussion on dbus interface](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=23580). I'm not really sure how to use this interface. If anyone is more familiar with dbus perhaps they can write an answer detailing various ways to access it via dbus.

Comment: The way I understand [the knotify API listing](http://api.kde.org/4.x-api/kdebase-runtime-apidocs/knotify/html/classKNotify.html), this should work: `qdbus org.kde.knotify /Notify event "warning" "origin" '(' ')' "title" "text" 0 0 0 0`. But it produces no visible effect when I test it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

kdialog method

```
kdialog --help # view options
kdialog --title syslog --passivepopup "foo" 2
```

Comment: Nice little utility! The package on archlinux is "kdebase-kdialog"